# Setting up a relationship class between two feature classes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, relationship-class

I am working on a project that involves a line feature class that represents roads and a point feature class that represents defects on the roads. I am trying to relate the point feature class to the line feature class so that when I select the road I am able to add a related point with the same name that represents a defect on that road.

I am having no trouble when I create a table and relate records to the line feature class but when I create the point feature class and try to relate it and add a new point in ArcMap I am not able to.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like [Linear Referencing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_referencing) is what you should be looking at. I began learning about it not too long ago, and I found the [ArcGIS Linear Referencing documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/linear-referencing/what-is-linear-referencing.htm) and [tutorial](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/linear-referencing/an-overview-of-the-linear-referencing-tutorial.htm) to be incredibly helpful. I suggest reading them carefully, follow along and perform the example exercise, and see if they will provide you with the functionality you're envisioning.

I primarily use QGIS, so after doing the tutorial in ArcGIS, I performed the same exercise within QGIS using the LRS Plugin and achieved the same result.